# Understanding [(a→b).(c→d)] formula in section 36 of The Logic of Scientific Discovery

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, popper

Excerpt from footnote 1 in section 36 of Popper's "The Logic of Scientific Discovery":

> In the present section, the arrow is used to express a conditional rather than the entailment relation.
>
> We can write ... [(a → b) . (c → d)] → [[(b → c) → (a → d)]

I understand that the dot, in logic notation, means "AND". But I don't quite see how this whole formula works. How can the second block be derived from the first? (block = statement bounded by "[]" brackets).

Comment: What do you mean by "derived"? The expression is explicitly not an entailment, just a statement that can be true or can be false. Nothing needs ot be derived.

Comment: It's the middle arrow that troubles me. Why is it there? Why not write the two blocks as two separate expressions that could be true or false?

Comment: Because he wants to express a conditional from the first to the second part that can be true or false, not two two isolated statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you quote is a tautology of the propositional calculus. To see this more clearly, we can use the import-export rule to move the (b → c) from the consequent into the antecedent. The formula is then equivalent to

[(a → b) . (b → c) . (c → d)] → (a → d)

and this is easier to understand, because it just says that if we chain a, b and c together then we can get from a to d.

In the context, Popper is making the point that if a property p is both more universal and more precise than some property q, then everything that is p is q. His discussion is rather laboured.

Also, he makes a mistake. He says,

> "p is of greater universality than q if the antecedent statement
> function of p [...] is tautologically implied by [...], but not
> equivalent to, the corresponding statement function of q."

However, the formula he writes, "(x)(Φ(sub q)(x) → Φ(sub p)(x))" does not capture the 'not equivalent to' part. His formula would allow that p and q are of equal universality.